# Qt 5.3 QPlainTextEdit Change the QTextCursor color

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I would like to change the cursor color under the `QPlainTextEdit` widget. I was able to set it's width to `6`, but I want to change the color or it. Is it possible ?

```
QFontMetrics fm(font());
setCursorWidth( fm.averageCharWidth() );
//setCursorColor is what I need.
```

Thanks.

Edit:

Including the images to exemplify...

From this:

[image: Initial Cursor Color]

To this:

[image]

Thanks.

Edit2: Final Look

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `QTextCharFormat` to set the color of the text in your `QPlainTextEdit`. Use the [`QTextCharFormat::setForeground`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextformat.html#setForeground) to set the color.
Then use a stylesheet to change the color of the cursor by using the `color` property.

```
QPlainTextEdit *p_textEdit = new QPlainTextEdit;
p_textEdit->setStyleSheet("QPlainTextEdit{color: #ffff00; background-color: #303030;"
                          " selection-background-color: #606060; selection-color: #ffffff;}");
QTextCharFormat fmt;
fmt.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(255,255,255)));
p_textEdit->mergeCurrentCharFormat(fmt);
```

Comment: I tried your solution in my sample (exposed in answer of [SO: Qt 5.8 QTextEdit Text Cursor Color Won't Change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889624/7478597)) but without luck. I came to the conclusion that this might work only on certain Qt style engines. Could you tell me which one do you used, or what I missed on my side?

Comment: @Scheff This seems to work on Qt 4.8 for me. Not on Qt 5.10. So it has stopped working somewhere between those two.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily mean it stopped working for Qt 5. Could be that it worked until Qt 5.5 for example. It seems that in the newer versions the cursor color is determined by the background color of the text edit.

Comment: @Scheff Seems like this changed in Qt 5.8: [See this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59093)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

You can change caret color with next stylesheet:

```
ui->plainTextEdit->setStyleSheet(
            "QPlainTextEdit"
            "{"
            "color: yellow;"
            "}"
            );
```

But there is another problem, all text becomes with this color too. How to set new color to text but left old color for caret? I found this solution, maybe not the best: use html code:

```
ui->plainTextEdit->appendHtml("<font color = \"red\"> Sample Text</font>");
```

Result (as you want original color for caret and for text):

[image]

Now text has needed color but caret has special color. It is solution, but it is a little dirty for me, if someone will find better way to change color of text without changing caret color, please tell this.

You can change only main cursor under widget:

```
QPixmap pix("pathToPixmap");
QCursor cur(pix);
ui->plainTextEdit->viewport()->setCursor(cur);
```

Qt has next embedded cursors: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#CursorShape-enum

Qt has not any cursor with specific color, so you should use you own pixmap. You can use image with simple arrow but with another color (if it has alpha-channel then it is better)

There are many different cursors in the web.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not what I need. I need to change the caret (blinking) to yellow ( from white ) for example. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: @matsjoyce It was just example from the web, but OP doesn't need this, so I deleted it.

Comment: @Yore I improved my answer. Check it please again.

Comment: I can't use that solution because of the nature of my editor (it's a complex editor). I can use stylesheet if it does not affect the entire QPlainTextEdit. I tried to change the style to QCursor, QTextCursor, but not functional.

Comment: I found a way to preserve my stylesheet and change the cursor color by using partially your solution. I will edit my question and post the result. thanks for the help ( again )