# How to force QPlainTextEdit to update its formattings?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, qplaintextedit

In slot connected to `QPlainTextEdit::textChanged()` signal I do syntax highlighting with:

```cpp
struct Format {
    QTextBlock block;
    QList< QTextLayout::FormatRange > format;
};

//! Formats.
QMap< int, Format > formats;

void clearFormats()
{
    for( const auto & f : std::as_const( formats ) )
        f.block.layout()->clearFormats();

    formats.clear();
}

void applyFormats()
{
    for( const auto & f : std::as_const( formats ) )
        f.block.layout()->setFormats( f.format );
}

void setFormat( const QTextCharFormat & format,
    long long int startLine, long long int startColumn,
    long long int endLine, long long int endColumn )
{
    for( auto i = startLine; i <= endLine; ++i )
    {
        formats[ i ].block = editor->document()->findBlockByNumber( i );

        QTextLayout::FormatRange r;
        r.format = format;
        r.start = ( i == startLine ? startColumn : 0 );
        r.length = ( i == startLine ?
            ( i == endLine ? endColumn - startColumn + 1 :
                formats[ i ].block.length() - startColumn ) :
            ( i == endLine ? endColumn + 1 : formats[ i ].block.length() ) );

        formats[ i ].format.push_back( r );
    }
}
```

On each text change I do the following:

```cpp
clearFormats();

setFormat( ... ); // When needed in text

applyFormats()
```

All works as expected when I'm typing a text in editor, syntax highlights.

In my application I have a dialog to set colors for syntax highlighting. On colors change I do above procedure with clearing formats, settings the new with new colors, and applying new formats.

And at this point of time colors remains the same, till I type something in editor.

So my question is: what should I do to force a `QPlainTextEdit` to apply new formats without typing anything?

Minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextCharFormat>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QTextBlock>


class Edit
    :   public QPlainTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Edit()
    {
        connect( this, &QPlainTextEdit::textChanged,
            this, &Edit::onTextChanged );
    }

    ~Edit() override = default;

public slots:
    void changeColor()
    {
        if( color == Qt::red )
            color = Qt::green;
        else
            color = Qt::red;

        emit textChanged();
    }

private slots:
    void onTextChanged()
    {
        clearFormats();
        setFormat();
    }

private:
    void clearFormats()
    {
        auto b = document()->firstBlock();

        while( b.isValid() )
        {
            b.layout()->clearFormats();

            b = b.next();
        }
    }

    void setFormat()
    {
        auto b = document()->firstBlock();

        QTextCharFormat f;
        f.setForeground( color );

        while( b.isValid() )
        {
            QTextLayout::FormatRange r;
            r.format = f;
            r.start = 0;
            r.length = b.length();

            b.layout()->setFormats( { r } );

            b = b.next();
        }
    }

private:
    QColor color = Qt::red;
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout l( &w );

    Edit e;
    l.addWidget( &e );
    QPushButton b;
    b.setText( "Change color" );
    l.addWidget( &b );
    b.connect( &b, &QPushButton::clicked, &e, &Edit::changeColor );

    w.resize( 800, 600 );
    w.show();


    return QApplication::exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: You could synthesize (speak: emit) the `textChanged()` signal after the colors have been changed. And, that could be as simple as `pEditor->textChanged();`.

Comment: It will be an infinite recursion.

Comment: How comes? It would mean that the change of colors happens somewhere nested inside one of your signal slots for `textChanged()`. And if so, why? Maybe, a [mcve] would help to sort this out. Just some fragments are not really sufficient...

Comment: I added into question an reproducible example, you welcome to play with it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. What was needed it's only update a view-port like:

```cpp
void changeColor()
{
    if( color == Qt::red )
        color = Qt::green;
    else
        color = Qt::red;

    emit textChanged();

    viewport()->update();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `textChanged()` imply a `viewport()->update()`?

Comment: Play a little with example at the bottom of the question. I second time caught an issue like this, `QAbstractScrollArea` very often requires `viewport()->update()` on similar tasks.

Comment: I'm fully aware why you used `viewport()->update()` instead of `update()`. I wondered about why it's necessary to force an update at all. But finally, I came myself to the conclusion why it is... (Of course, the `QPlainTextEdit` doesn't react on its own changes. I was confused by the fact that changing the text from outside usually should result in a textChanged signal _and_ an update as well, but this doesn't apply here.)

Comment: And, btw. I already did [play with QTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889624/7478597) multiple times - no need so far. :-)

Comment: Considering that we're dealing with QPlainTextEdit and such changes in formatting are not *actual* text changes, the proper signal(s) should probably be those of the document's layout: [`updateBlock()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.html#updateBlock), or, better, if no unique block can be identified for the format changes, [`update()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.html#update).